how duplicate models around the objects
I have a problem, I'm learning how to use shrink, I want to attach another model to the sphere, and it's working
But now I want to duplicate this attached object and place it in other parts of the sphere, but it's getting deformed.

It actually looks like the object is just maintaining its orientation, but I want change orientation according to plane.
I can rotate the object and place it in the proper position

but I wanted to know if there's a more precise way to do this, for example automatically rotating along the normal, because rotating manually always has imperfections, and it takes a little time to get the right rotation..

If you have a sphere, all you have to do is rotate the part around the center of it:

You have to place the 3d cursor at the center of your sphere. Maybe use Snap menu( Shift  +  S ) with the middle loop of your sphere selected in edit mode to snap 3d cursor to selected. And then you need to choose the 3d cursor as transform pivot point. You can duplicate( Shift  +  D ) or duplicate linked( Alt  +  D )and rotate imediately ( R ), then enter the rotation value numerically.  Shift  +  R  repeats last operation so you can then make multiple copies rotated the same amount quickly.

I can't believe I didn't think about that, thanks!!! But it will work here because it's a sphere, it's proportional at all angles, but if it were a more complex object, would be even more problematic.

You can use snapping with Align Rotation to Target enabled, you need to make sure the origin of the object is where you want it to be(if you are using Active as Snap Base) and that the object is oriented in the way you want - Z axis of the object will point away from surface same as its normals.

Bu I would say "on object's surface" not "around the object" then, so I thought that's outside the scope of the question.
